# How write a MsSQl query for this scenerio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to MS SQL.

I had a problem in writing a query for this particular scenario So can any one help me

I have table as

```
 S.no  Sender Recevier  Function  
  1       s1     R1        Read
  2       R1     S1        Read
  3       S1     P1        Write
  4       R1     w2        Read
```

I would Update the values based on following criteria

```
  that is Select the Function Read Where (Sender = S1) OR (Receiver = S1)
```

That I need Update the values By Selecting a Function And User may be in Sender coloumn or receiver  So How can I do it.

I trited like

```
Update Table1 Set Sender = Null, Receiver=Null Where Function = 'Read' And Sender = 's1'OR Receiver = 's1'
```

But I am Unsucessful So please any one help me how solve this.

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.. unless @jpw has it right that is.

Comment: Based on your description the where clause should be ....  Where `Function` = 'Read' And ( Sender = 's1' OR Receiver = 's1' ) -- notice the parenthesis

Comment: I would guess 'function' is a keyword in MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you get an error like `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Function'.:` when you run this because the word `function` is a [reserved keyword in T-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Try changing it to:

```
Update Table1 Set Sender = Null, Receiver = Null 
Where [Function] = 'Read' And (Sender = 's1' OR Receiver = 's1')
```

You might want to change the name of the column if possible as using reserved word is never a good idea.

Sample [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e171d/3).

Comment: Ho thank you It is working now for me And sure I will change my column Name